# Simple macro for new # symbol

Tags: errors, symbols

I was unsatisfied with how the # symbol looked in my document and had a look at [this question](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwidwM2Z1rPhAhUb5uAKHdSjDecQFjAAegQIBhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftex.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F256553%2Fhow-can-i-get-a-better-pound-symbol-number-sign-hash-character&usg=AOvVaw0xz87uQe1tAlhhjvP3Dty-). I tried to create a simple macro to replace

```
#
```

with

```
\texttt{\#}
```

I thought that a simple

```
\renewcommand{\#}{\texttt{\#}}
```

would do the trick. Instead, I'm getting a fatal (!) error.

```
[25] [26] [27] [28] [29] (c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1cmtt.fd)
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].
\hmode@bgroup ->\leavevmode \bgroup 


!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on Thesis.log.
```

What is going wrong and why? How can I succesfully create the macro I need?

Comment: Since LaTeX is a macro expansion language you essentially tell LaTeX to replace every occurrence of `\#` with `\texttt{\#}`. Since the replacement text (`\texttt{\#}`) contains `\#` again you end up with an infinite loop of replacements being attempted. After a while TeX gives up because its capacity is exceeded.

Comment: In that case a trick like `\let\oldhash\#  \renewcommand{\#}{\texttt{\oldhash}}` usually helps. The `\let\oldhash\#` copies the definition of `\#` into `\oldhash` and you can then use `\oldhash` in the replacement of `\#` to get the same effect but without the loop. Another way would be `\renewcommand{\#}{\texttt{\char"23}}` if you know where the `#` lives in your font. That said, I'm not quite sure if it is absolutely safe to redefine `\#`, so I would probably choose a new name making it unnecessary to avoid the loop.

Comment: `\let\hashtag\#\renewcommand\#{\texttt{\hashtag}}` does work. Though, I'd just define `\hashtag` to be `\texttt{\#}` and then use `\hashtag` throughout.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot define a command in terms of itself like that, because upon finding `\#` TeX will replace it by `\texttt{\#}`, then replacing it by `\texttt{\texttt{\#}}` and so on.

Solution for the particular case

```
\renewcommand{\#}{\texttt{\symbol{`\#}}}
```

because the standard definition of `\#` is a streamlined form of `` \symbol{`\#} ``.

For other situations when `\command` just produces text,

```
\let\standardcommand=\command
\renewcommand{\command}{\texttt{\standardcommand}}
```

would work.